# What is the $\ell_{2,\infty}$ matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms) defines the matrix $\ell_{p,q}$ matrix norm.

I was wondering what exactly the $\ell_{2,\infty}$ norm would be?

Comment: The formula on Wikipedia suggests that you get kind-of-a vector: $\tilde{a} = (\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{ij}|^2 )^{1/2}$ (operations are element-wise), after summing the inner part. After getting $\tilde{a}$, just take the infinity norm over it. That is $\|A\|_{2,\infty}=\max_j|\tilde{a}_j|$ for the above $\tilde{a}$.

Comment: The logic is same for $\ell_{\infty, p}$ for some $p$, you just first get a vector of maximal elements from the rows of $A$, to which you apply the $p$-norm.

Comment: So the $\ell_{2,\infty}$ norm is the maximum column euclidean norm?

Comment: Well, I guess, you can think of it like that, right

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I heard in the past that it was rowwise instead.

Comment: Also, why is that when we take the limit this gives the infinity norm which is the max entry?

Comment: @o.spectrum So we can think of the inner part being a vector made of entries of the column euclidean norms and then applying the vector infinity norm, which as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/858498/762889) is the max entry.